# NodeJS response.render():Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, the first render is successful `app.get("/", function(request, response)`, but when I process `app.post("/search", urlencodedParser, function(request, response)`

I get the Error:

> c:\weather\views\main.hbs: Can't set headers after they are sent.

I read that, `The function`res.render()`should only be called once per request.`, but I don't understand - How Can I change datas using `views(Handlebars)`, if i can't call render again with new datas?

```js
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var hbs = require("hbs");
// create object
var app = express();
//urlEncoded
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
});
//read city.json
var content = fs.readFileSync("./city.list.json", "utf8");
var cities = JSON.parse(content);
//set view Handlebars
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
//register Helper - ResultBlock
hbs.registerHelper("ResultBlock", function(array) {
  var res = "";
  if (array[0] == "false") {
    res = '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Not Found!</strong> The ' + array[1] + ' is not correct.</div>';
  } else if (array[0] == "true") {
    res = 'Succsesful!!!';
  }
  return new hbs.SafeString(res);
})
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
  //response.sendfile('index.html');
  response.render("main.hbs", {
    city_value: "Zaporozhye",
    data: []
  })
});
app.post("/search", urlencodedParser, function(request, response) {
  var city = request.body.city;
  var idCity = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    if (cities[i].name == city) {
      idCity = cities[i].id;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (idCity != -1) {
    response.render("main.hbs", {
      city_value: city,
      data: ["true", city]
    })
  } else {
    response.render("main.hbs", {
      city_value: city,
      data: ["false", city]
    })
  }
  response.end();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="app.js" type=""></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:black; color:darkorange;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>Weather</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-*-*">
        <form action="/search" method="post">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" value="{{city_value}}" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="result_block" class="container">
    {{ResultBlock data}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`response.render` is an asynchronous function. So the rendering is done after the current execution context finish.

At the end of your code your call `response.end()` and because of that you finish the response before the rendering has started.

After you finished the response the asynchronous rendering function will start and tries to set the headers, but this is not possible because the response is already finished, and that's the reason why you get that error.

Remove the `response.end()` and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete response.end() line, since you used response.render

Answer (score 0):

The function [response.end()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end) is used the send the headers of the response and ends the response process.

On the other hand, the function [response.render()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) renders the view, and also sends the headers and ends the response.

Calling both on the same response object will try to send headers twice for the same Request, which is not possible as each request can have only one response.

---

So, removing the `response.end()` from the end of post route handler for '/search' should solve the problem.

Updated Code for '/search' POST route handler:

```
app.post("/search", urlencodedParser, function(request, response) {
  var city = request.body.city;
  var idCity = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    if (cities[i].name == city) {
      idCity = cities[i].id;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (idCity != -1) {
    response.render("main.hbs", {
      city_value: city,
      data: ["true", city]
    })
  } else {
    response.render("main.hbs", {
      city_value: city,
      data: ["false", city]
    })
  }
});
```